# how 'while (*dst++ = *src++) ;' be executed?

Tags: c

I read this in a strcpy funciton.

```
while (*dst++ = *src++)
    ;
```

I'm not really sure the execute order. who can help me?

Comment: Operator precedence says `postfix > unary > assignment`, and finally the `iteration-statement` will evaluate the `null-statement` every time its controlling expression evaluates as non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postfix `++` operator increments the value of a variable after the statement it's in has been executed. According to C's precedence rules, the expression will be evaluated something like this:

```
while (*(dst++) = *(src++));
```

Which will basically:

1. Set the character `dst` points to to the character `src` points to.
2. Increment both `dst` and `src`
3. If the character was `'\0'`, end the loop.
4. Otherwise, repeat.

Comment: So,  '\0' is not be copied, right?

Comment: Since the loop copes the character before it checks the value, yes, the `'\0'` will be copied. Also, if I answered your question, make sure to accept it.

Comment: @protream "right?" Obviously not right according to this description. Step 1 copies the char. Step 3 checks whether it is '\0'.